# Android TListBox does not scroll smoothly

Tags: android, performance, delphi, listbox, firemonkey

I'm using a `TListBox` component to display a list with `CheckBoxes`.

It works very well on `iOS`, but on `Android` it generates a small lag when scrolling.

At the first glance, I thought it would be due it's design of each `TListBoxItem` being a container of `Controls`. However, when generating a simple List (***without*** `CheckBoxes`) it remains to lag a little bit.

Is it a problem with the component?

Is there any solution that does not evolve removing any of my `ListBoxes`?

Comment: Quite possible that thinks have changed in the latest version of Delphi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### For the first question

> Note: FMX.ListBox.TListBox performance can be slow on mobile. Use TListView if you want to develop more complex applications, especially apps with large databases.

From [Embarcadero docwiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Mobile_Tutorial:_Using_ListBox_Components_to_Display_a_Table_View_%28iOS_and_Android%29)

#### For the second question

There may be. My solution would be to swap `TListBox` to `TListView`
If you need checkboxes in your listbox you can also do it with `TListView`. Set `AccessosoryType` to `CheckBoxes`.

Comment: Thank you for answering both questions. It seems to be a component issue and I'll try to switch them to `ListView`.